Overflow scroll in flex container
I have searched the internet for this problem, but there are so many variations of this problem that none of the provided solutions work in my case. I have asked ChatGPT and it can't help me either.
Here is my html structure:
<div id="editor">
    <iframe id="preview" title="editor preview"></iframe>

    <div id="chat-container" class="chat-centered">
        <div id="chat-header">
            <span id="chat-title">Bot</span>
            <button id="minimize-button">&minus;</button>
        </div>
        <div id="chat-messages">

        </div>
        <div id="chat-input">
            <div id="input-box" contenteditable="true"></div>
            <button id="send-button">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="chat-toggle-button"></button>
</div>

Here is the relevant css:
#chat-container {
    color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

#chat-messages {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

The chat-messages div needs to scroll on overflow. However on every browser I tested it refuses to do this.
I have added height, min-height, position and flex-basis to both child and parent. All with undesired results, and not with the desired result.
I have even tried nesting the div in another, with the outer one 'flexing' and the inner one positioned absolute. To my surprise, that didn't scroll either.
There is clearly something I am not understanding. So, I turn to you.
ps. I have a live version running on patsboemwebsite.nl but you have to click 'Start nu je website' in order to see it.

In Chrome use F12 key. Find <div id="chat-messages"></div>. Right-click that element and pick Edit as HTML. Place about 100 lines of text within that element then click elsewhere.

It turns out, having justify-content: flex-end; will make scrollbars disappear. For now I can do without, but it is unfortunate.
